# Inherited Static Factory Method Returning Child Class Type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, factory

I have a `Logging` class that is inherited by `LoggingString`, `LoggingInt`, etc. which each have a `writeLog` function that takes in the corresponding type:

```
class Logging {
public:
    explicit Logging(const LoggingConfig& config);
...
}

class LoggingString : public Logging {
public:
    using Logging::Logging;

    writeLog(std::string str);
...
}
```

In the code where I use LoggingString, I want to be able to call a factory function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<LoggingString> logger = LoggingString::CreateIfLoggingEnabled(LoggingConfig{...});
std::unique_ptr<LoggingInt> logger = LoggingInt::CreateIfLoggingEnabled(LoggingConfig{...});
```

Considering they're all using the same constructor derived from the base `Logging` class, is it possible to put this `static Logging::CreateIfLoggingEnabled` function in the base class and somehow have it inherited by the `Logging` derived classes, but returning a `unique_ptr<LoggingDerivedClass>` instead? Maybe something with templating like this:

```
class Logging {
public:
    explicit Logging(const LoggingConfig& config);

    template<typename T> static std::unique_ptr<T> CreateIfLoggingEnabled(const LoggingConfig& config) {
        ...
        return std::unique_ptr<T>{};
    }
...
}

std::unique_ptr<LoggingString> logger = LoggingString::CreateIfLoggingEnabled<LoggingString>(LoggingConfig{...});
```

Not sure if this would work, and besides it seems redundant to have to specify `LoggingString` twice. Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems redundant to have to specify `LoggingString` twice.

You wouldn't have to specify `LoggingString` twice (thrice if you count the `logger` variable declaration).  You can replace `LoggingString::` with `Logging::`, and use `auto` for the variable, eg:

```cpp
class Logging {
public:
    explicit Logging(const LoggingConfig& config);

    template<typename T>
    static std::unique_ptr<T> CreateIfLoggingEnabled(const LoggingConfig& config) {
        ...
        return std::make_unique<T>(config);
    }
    ...
};
```

```cpp
auto logger = Logging::CreateIfLoggingEnabled<LoggingString>(LoggingConfig{...});
```

```cpp
auto logger = Logging::CreateIfLoggingEnabled<LoggingInt>(LoggingConfig{...});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rNowuG)

Alternatively, you can use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to pass the derived type into the base class, eg:

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
class Logging {
public:
    explicit Logging(const LoggingConfig& config);

    static std::unique_ptr<Derived> CreateIfLoggingEnabled(const LoggingConfig& config) {
        ...
        return std::make_unique<Derived>(config);
    }
    ...
};

class LoggingString : public Logging<LoggingString> {
public:
    using Logging<LoggingString>::Logging;

    void writeLog(std::string str);
    ...
};

class LoggingInt : public Logging<LoggingInt> {
public:
    using Logging<LoggingInt>::Logging;

    void writeLog(int i);
    ...
};
```

```cpp
auto logger = LoggingString::CreateIfLoggingEnabled(LoggingConfig{...});
```

```cpp
auto logger = LoggingInt::CreateIfLoggingEnabled(LoggingConfig{...});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PNwA0x)

Comment: good point! I guess I was wondering if it's possible to do something like `auto logger = LoggingString::CreateIfLoggingEnabled(LoggingConfig{...});` and have the factory function always return the type of the inherited class. Something like `return std::unique_ptr<this>{};`.

Comment: You should be able to use CRTP for that. I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: I was not aware of CRTP. That seems like what I'm looking for. Thanks!